# CSS issue: <div> element overlaying other <div> elements when trying to put it below

Tags: html, css

I am starting my approach to CCS and I face my first difficulties.

I have a `<div>` container and 2 overlaying `<div>` elements inside the container managed by CSS classes. These three elements are working properly as I want.

But when I add an other  element outside the container that I am expecting to show up below the container it overlays on the other elements. I tried to use flexbox instructions but it did not work.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: #0057e3;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 600px;
  margin: 70px;
  background: #009938;
}

.imgA {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 450px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"><img src="yyyyyyyyyyyyy"></div>
  <div class="box overlay">
    <img class="imgA" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Why this one overlays?</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Because box is positioned absolutely so they are removed from normal flow. So container as no height.

Comment: Both `.box` and `.overlay` are set `position: absolute`. This pulls them out of the render flow. Because of that, `.container` doesn't have any content that contributes to its rendering. Since `.container` also doesn't have a height, it collapses to a height of 0.

Comment: like @Sfili_81 said its because of the `position: absolute` if you want `overlay` to overlay the `.box` remove the `absolute` from `.box` so that it is not removed from the normal flow and only give `absolute` to the overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.container** *does not have a `height` set and that's where the main problem is happening in your case.*

Since there are two `absolute` positioned divs within your container. The two divs comes out of the normal flow. And your container height stays 0. Since you are not explicitly giving any height to container div.

If you add some height to the container, that will take height in the normal flow and overlay of last div would not happen.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:400px; /* Added Height */
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
 
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 70px;
}

.imgA {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 450px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box overlay">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
    </div
    <div class="box overlay">
      <img class="imgA" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Why this one overlays?</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: U are welcome :) Do vote and accept the answer. The pleasure is all mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .container {
          width: 100%;
          position: relative;
          /* background-color: #0057e3; */
          
        }
        
        .box {
          width: 100%;
          /* height: 100%; */
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          opacity: 0.7;
          background: #0057e3;
        }
        .box img{
            height: 400px;
        }
        
        .overlay {
          z-index: 2;
          /* width: 20%; */
          position: relative;
          margin-top: 600px;
          /* margin: 70px; */
          background: #009938;
        }
        
        .imgA {
          max-width: 300px;
          max-height: 450px;
          display: block;
        }
        .section-2{
            border: 1px solid #0057e3;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="pic2.JPG">
    </div>
    <div class="box overlay">
      <img class="imgAh" src="pic1.JPG">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='section-2'>
    <h1>Why this one overlays?</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  To help others understand how this solves the question, can you [edit] your answer and provide a brief description of the parts that help.  Thanks.